# How to check version of GNU make in mac terminal?

Tags: makefile, version, gnu

Title says it all. I googled around but only found methods using rpm, which is not installed on my mac.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way would be to run `make --version`. E.g., on my machine it outputs:

```
mureinik@computer ~$ make --version 
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 2):

To display the version, type the following in the terminal:

```
make -v
```

Which on my machine gave the following output:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```